# Did SE stop sending automated email when a ticket is created using contact page?

Tags: support, email, contact

[In the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368740/), after creating a ticket using the [contact page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact), an email like this was sent by SE:

> We are confirming that your request has been received. You do not need to reply to this message unless you have further information to add.

[image]

Lately, I haven't been receiving these kinda emails when I create a ticket. So, did SE stop sending these emails?

Comment: Related, opposite question: [Since when did Stack Exchange start sending automated mails when one contacts Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368740/since-when-did-stack-exchange-start-sending-automated-mails-when-one-contacts-st)

Comment: I remember animuson saying something along the lines of "we stopped sending auto confirmations because they made people think their case is going to be handled quickly, while that's not the case" but can't find it.

Comment: That's Grace Note, and its the post you just linked?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek no, Cesar. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380908/isnt-a-reply-to-an-se-email-monitored-as-a-ticket-is-closed#comment1270706_380928). Oh wait, never mind thought you asked who asked the OP to send new ticket.

Comment: @Shadow Sounds vaguely familiar, but so many things have changed since then. It looks like we only send them to tickets that reach Product Support and not Community Support, but as I am no longer involved in Community Support, I cannot say what reasons led to that decision.

Comment: @animuson I would be grateful to you if you could ask someone from Community Support to answer the question :)

Comment: @animuson well, so this is at least semi-answer, better than nothing that's sure. Thanks! :)